# How to notify a stream to update in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pagination, flutter-change-notifier

I am trying to implement pagination in my Flutter app but this is the first time I have done it. My idea was to create a `Stream` of data that updates each time the user reaches the bottom of a list. I have failed to get this working. My current code has the logic for getting the new data and adding it to the existing data, but right now it's not even returning the first range of data so the snapshots are empty. As for the pagination functionality, I tried to use a `ChangeNotifier` to notify the `Stream` to update, but I don't know if that is working. Please take a look at the code below and let me know what should be changed.

The `DataProvider` class:

```
class DataProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  DataProvider() : super();

  static var changeController = ChangeNotifier();

  static void reload() {
    changeController.notifyListeners();
  }

  static int lastRange = 0;

  static List data = [];

  static Stream<List> paginatedUsersAndPosts() async* {
    List<UserSearchResult> usersList = data.first;
    List<Post> postsList = data.last;

    print('Notifier');

    changeController.addListener(() async {
      print('Change notified, getting data');

      List<int> range() {
        if (lastRange == 0) {
          lastRange = 10;
          return [0, 10];
        } else {
          // Example 0, 10 => 11, 20
          int newMin = lastRange + 1;
          int newMax = lastRange + 10;
          lastRange = newMax;
          return [newMin, newMax];
        }
      }

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> postsDocs = await Supabase.db
          .from('posts')
          .select()
          .order('date', ascending: false)
          .range(range().first, range().last);
      List<Post> newPostsList =
      postsDocs.map((postDoc) => Post.fromJson(postDoc)).toList();

      newPostsList.forEach((post) async {
        postsList.add(post);

        if (usersList.where((u) => u.uid == post.uid).isNotEmpty) {
          Map<String, dynamic> userDoc =
          await Supabase.db.from('profiles').select().single();

          ProfileInfoObject profileInfo = ProfileInfoObject.fromJson(userDoc);
          print('New profile: $profileInfo');
          Profile profile = Profile(profileInfo, []);
          profile.posts.add(post);
          List blockedUsers = userDoc['blockedUsers'] as List;
          UserSearchResult user = (UserSearchResult(
              profile, userDoc['uid'].toString(), blockedUsers));

          usersList.add(user);
        }
      });
    });

    yield [usersList, postsList];
  }
}
```

The main widget that uses the stream:

```
class FloatingTabBarView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloatingTabBarView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FloatingTabBarView> createState() => _FloatingTabBarViewState();
}

class _FloatingTabBarViewState extends State<FloatingTabBarView> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    PermissionsService.checkPermissions(context);

    DataProvider.reload();
    super.initState();
  }

    Stream<List> stream = DataProvider.paginatedUsersAndPosts();

    return StreamBuilder<List>(
        stream: stream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
          ...
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return floatingTabBarPageView();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the way I was creating the stream. Since I made the `Stream` a function, there was no way for me to call that function to reload. Instead, I moved the code to a `static void` that I can call from any page, created a `StreamController`, and used `controller.add(data)` at the end of the `void` which allows me to update the stream with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) package. This allows to implement pull to refresh and incrementally load data. Use the `RefreshController` to update when the data is refreshed or loaded.

1. Instantiate `RefreshController`
2. Wrap the `ListView` with `SmartRefresher`
3. Implement the `onLoading` callback to fetch data incrementally
4. Update the `RefreshController` on completion or error.

The package has a good [usage example](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh#usage), do check it out.